# Perché a volte si scrive l'accento grafico in parole sdrucciole o piane?

Tags: orthography, accents

So che in italiano si deve scrivere l'accento grafico quando l'accento tonico è sull'ultima sillaba della parola, ma a volte ho visto parole sdrucciole (ad esempio, *fascìcolo*) o piane (per esempio, *quaternióne*) con l'accento grafico. Si tratta di un fatto usuale in alcuni dizionari, ma ho anche visto alcuni di questi vocaboli accentati in qualche romanzo. Qual è la ragione per cui si scrivono tali accenti?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ci possono essere vari motivi.

Il più frequente è quello di distinguere tra omografi (parole che si scrivono nello stesso modo) non omofoni (e che quindi si pronunciano diversamente). Un caso frequente è quello dei plurali di “principe” e di “principio”, che diventano entrambi “principi” (anche se il secondo si potrebbe, o dovrebbe, scrivere “principii” o “principî”). In questo caso, specie se il contesto dà adito ad ambiguità (“i principi della filosofia”) si tende a mettere l'accento grafico per chiarire quale delle due parole si stia usando, talvolta anche nel caso di una parola piana: «i princìpi della matematica». Un caso simile vale per “àncora” e “ancóra”, “càpitano” e “capitàno” etc. (vedi [qui](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/omografi_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/) per più lumi).

Poi c'è una scuola di pensiero minoritaria che vorrebbe indicare l'accento grafico su tutte le parole non piane: lo scrittore [Carlo Dossi](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlo_Dossi) ne era persuaso al punto da rendere quasi illeggibili i suoi scritti. La sua *Desinenza in A* ha addirittura un'avvertenza iniziale in cui spiega: «l'“*accento grave* (`)” [...], seguendo la regola di Carlo Cattaneo, già seguita da Pàolo Gorini e da altri, fu impiegato a segnare tutte le parole non solo tronche (*precipitò*) ma semitronche (*precipitài*) nonché sdrucciole (*precìpiti*), bisdrùcciole (*precìpitano*) e trisdrucciole (*precìpitanosi*). Le parole senza accento dèbbono quindi considerarsi come piane (*precipitare*) o semipiane (*precipuo*).
Dell'accento acuto (´) non s'è fatto caso, ritenendolo superfluo; né si adoperò il 
circonflesso che a semplice indicazione delle parole sincopate (*raccôrre* per 
*raccògliere*)».

> ¿Da qual caminetto di letterato o banco di drogherìa, da qual latrina di gazzettiere o biblioteca in saccheggio bonghiano, hai tù, mio temerario editore, saputo salvarmi questa copia rarìssima della prima edizione della «Desinenza in A», che t'intestasti a ristampare?

(La grafia del Dossi aveva anche altre peculiarità, come si vede, tra cui i punti esclamativo e interrogativo ribaltati all'inizio delle frasi, sul modello spagnolo. [Qui](http://www.liberliber.it/libri/d/dossi/index.php) se ne possono trovare alcune opere.)

Infine, l'esempio del “quaternióne” sarà probabilmente dovuto anche a un desiderio di chiarire, per una parola insolita, che quella “o” è chiusa.

Comment: Bizzarro uso dell'accento in *quaternione*; il suffisso *-one* trascina l'accento tonico sulla *o*, che è chiusa in tutti gli esempi che mi vengono in mente (parlate regionali a parte).